# ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 121 layers into a model with 120 layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I see that there are already couple of questions regarding this issue, and some of the answers talk about excluding **Input** object from the model. However, is that even possible when you are using **Keras Functional API**? Anyways, here is my problem. I have same custom ResNet class which I am trying to instantiate using pretrained model weights. But, when I try to do that I get the following error:

```
ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 121 layers into a model with 120 layers.
```

I've traced the source code of the problem and it seems to be in hdf5_format.py file. I've also altered the code by inserting some print functions in order to have a more productive visual inspection. Here is the code from the hdf5_format.py file (I've put couple of comments on the parts where you should pay attention):

```
def load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f, layers):
  """Implements topological (order-based) weight loading.

  Arguments:
      f: A pointer to a HDF5 group.
      layers: a list of target layers.

  Raises:
      ValueError: in case of mismatch between provided layers
          and weights file.
  """
  if 'keras_version' in f.attrs:
    original_keras_version = f.attrs['keras_version'].decode('utf8')
  else:
    original_keras_version = '1'
  if 'backend' in f.attrs:
    original_backend = f.attrs['backend'].decode('utf8')
  else:
    original_backend = None

  filtered_layers = []
  for layer in layers:
    weights = _legacy_weights(layer)
    if weights:
      filtered_layers.append(layer)
      
  layer_names = load_attributes_from_hdf5_group(f, 'layer_names')
  filtered_layer_names = []
  for name in layer_names:
    g = f[name]
    weight_names = load_attributes_from_hdf5_group(g, 'weight_names')
    if weight_names:
      filtered_layer_names.append(name)
  ### INSERTED PRINT FUNCTION FOR DEBUGGING PURPOSES
  for ln, fl in zip(layer_names, filtered_layers):
    print("Layer name: {} | Filtered Layer Name: {}".format(ln, fl.name))

  layer_names = filtered_layer_names
  #### CODE BREAKS HERE ###
  if len(layer_names) != len(filtered_layers):
    raise ValueError('You are trying to load a weight file '
                     'containing ' + str(len(layer_names)) +
                     ' layers into a model with ' + str(len(filtered_layers)) +
                     ' layers.')**

  # We batch weight value assignments in a single backend call
  # which provides a speedup in TensorFlow.
  weight_value_tuples = []
  for k, name in enumerate(layer_names):
    g = f[name]
    weight_names = load_attributes_from_hdf5_group(g, 'weight_names')
    weight_values = [np.asarray(g[weight_name]) for weight_name in weight_names]
    layer = filtered_layers[k]
    symbolic_weights = _legacy_weights(layer)
    weight_values = preprocess_weights_for_loading(
        layer, weight_values, original_keras_version, original_backend)
    if len(weight_values) != len(symbolic_weights):
      raise ValueError('Layer #' + str(k) + ' (named "' + layer.name +
                       '" in the current model) was found to '
                       'correspond to layer ' + name + ' in the save file. '
                       'However the new layer ' + layer.name + ' expects ' +
                       str(len(symbolic_weights)) +
                       ' weights, but the saved weights have ' +
                       str(len(weight_values)) + ' elements.')
    weight_value_tuples += zip(symbolic_weights, weight_values)
  K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)
```

And here is the output I am getting from my print function:

```
Layer name: input_6 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_59
Layer name: batch_normalization_236 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_61
Layer name: conv2d_244 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_60
Layer name: batch_normalization_237 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_62
Layer name: activation_236 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_61
Layer name: conv2d_245 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_63
Layer name: batch_normalization_238 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_62
Layer name: activation_237 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_64
Layer name: conv2d_246 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_65
Layer name: batch_normalization_239 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_63
Layer name: activation_238 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_66
Layer name: conv2d_247 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_64
Layer name: conv2d_248 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_67
Layer name: add_76 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_65
Layer name: batch_normalization_240 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_68
Layer name: activation_239 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_66
Layer name: conv2d_249 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_69
Layer name: batch_normalization_241 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_67
Layer name: activation_240 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_70
Layer name: conv2d_250 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_68
Layer name: batch_normalization_242 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_71
Layer name: activation_241 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_69
Layer name: conv2d_251 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_72
Layer name: add_77 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_70
Layer name: batch_normalization_243 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_73
Layer name: activation_242 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_71
Layer name: conv2d_252 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_74
Layer name: batch_normalization_244 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_72
Layer name: activation_243 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_75
Layer name: conv2d_253 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_73
Layer name: batch_normalization_245 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_76
Layer name: activation_244 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_74
Layer name: conv2d_254 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_77
Layer name: add_78 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_78
Layer name: batch_normalization_246 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_75
Layer name: activation_245 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_79
Layer name: conv2d_255 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_76
Layer name: batch_normalization_247 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_80
Layer name: activation_246 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_77
Layer name: conv2d_256 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_81
Layer name: batch_normalization_248 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_78
Layer name: activation_247 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_82
Layer name: conv2d_257 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_79
Layer name: add_79 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_83
Layer name: batch_normalization_249 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_80
Layer name: activation_248 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_84
Layer name: conv2d_258 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_81
Layer name: batch_normalization_250 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_85
Layer name: activation_249 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_82
Layer name: conv2d_259 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_86
Layer name: batch_normalization_251 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_83
Layer name: activation_250 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_87
Layer name: conv2d_260 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_84
Layer name: conv2d_261 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_88
Layer name: add_80 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_85
Layer name: batch_normalization_252 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_89
Layer name: activation_251 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_86
Layer name: conv2d_262 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_90
Layer name: batch_normalization_253 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_87
Layer name: activation_252 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_91
Layer name: conv2d_263 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_88
Layer name: batch_normalization_254 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_92
Layer name: activation_253 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_89
Layer name: conv2d_264 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_93
Layer name: add_81 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_90
Layer name: batch_normalization_255 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_94
Layer name: activation_254 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_91
Layer name: conv2d_265 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_95
Layer name: batch_normalization_256 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_92
Layer name: activation_255 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_96
Layer name: conv2d_266 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_97
Layer name: batch_normalization_257 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_93
Layer name: activation_256 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_98
Layer name: conv2d_267 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_94
Layer name: add_82 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_99
Layer name: batch_normalization_258 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_95
Layer name: activation_257 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_100
Layer name: conv2d_268 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_96
Layer name: batch_normalization_259 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_101
Layer name: activation_258 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_97
Layer name: conv2d_269 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_102
Layer name: batch_normalization_260 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_98
Layer name: activation_259 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_103
Layer name: conv2d_270 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_99
Layer name: add_83 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_104
Layer name: batch_normalization_261 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_100
Layer name: activation_260 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_105
Layer name: conv2d_271 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_101
Layer name: batch_normalization_262 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_106
Layer name: activation_261 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_102
Layer name: conv2d_272 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_107
Layer name: batch_normalization_263 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_103
Layer name: activation_262 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_108
Layer name: conv2d_273 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_104
Layer name: add_84 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_109
Layer name: batch_normalization_264 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_105
Layer name: activation_263 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_110
Layer name: conv2d_274 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_106
Layer name: batch_normalization_265 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_111
Layer name: activation_264 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_107
Layer name: conv2d_275 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_112
Layer name: batch_normalization_266 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_108
Layer name: activation_265 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_113
Layer name: conv2d_276 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_109
Layer name: add_85 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_114
Layer name: batch_normalization_267 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_110
Layer name: activation_266 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_115
Layer name: conv2d_277 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_111
Layer name: batch_normalization_268 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_116
Layer name: activation_267 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_112
Layer name: conv2d_278 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_117
Layer name: batch_normalization_269 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_113
Layer name: activation_268 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_118
Layer name: conv2d_279 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_114
Layer name: conv2d_280 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_119
Layer name: add_86 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_115
Layer name: batch_normalization_270 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_120
Layer name: activation_269 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_116
Layer name: conv2d_281 | Filtered Layer Name: conv2d_121
Layer name: batch_normalization_271 | Filtered Layer Name: batch_normalization_117
```

By visually inspecting the output I am guessing that the problem is in the `Input` layer. But, how do I actually resolve this if I am using **Functional API**. Here is code for my `ResNet` class.

```
class ResNet:
  @staticmethod
  def residual_module(data, K, stride, chanDim, reduce=False, reg=0.0001, bnEps=2e-5, bnMom=0.9):
    shortcut = data
    
    bn1 = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim, epsilon=bnEps, momentum=bnMom)(data)
    act1 = Activation("relu")(bn1)
    conv1 = Conv2D(int(K * 0.25), (1, 1), use_bias=False, kernel_regularizer=l2(reg))(act1)
    
    bn2 = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim, epsilon=bnEps, momentum=bnMom)(conv1)
    act2 = Activation("relu")(bn2)
    conv2 = Conv2D(int(K * 0.25), (3, 3), strides=stride, padding="same", use_bias=False, kernel_regularizer=l2(reg))(act2)
    
    bn3 = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim, epsilon=bnEps, momentum=bnMom)(conv2)
    act3 = Activation("relu")(bn3)
    conv3 = Conv2D(K, (1, 1), use_bias=False, kernel_regularizer=l2(reg))(act3)
    
    if reduce:
      shortcut = Conv2D(K, (1, 1), strides=stride, use_bias=False, kernel_regularizer=l2(reg))(act1)
    
    x = add([conv3, shortcut])
    return x


  @staticmethod
  def build(width, height, depth, classes, stages, filters, reg=0.0001, bnEps=2e-5, bnMom=0.9,
              include_top=True, weights=None):
      input_shape = (height, width, depth)
      chan_dim = -1
      
      if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
        input_shape = (depth, height, width)
        chan_dim = 1
      
      inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
      x = BatchNormalization(axis=chan_dim,input_shape=input_shape, epsilon=bnEps, momentum=bnMom)(inputs)
      x = Conv2D(filters[0], (3, 3),input_shape=input_shape, use_bias=False, padding="same", kernel_regularizer=l2(reg))(x)
      
      for i in range(0, len(stages)):
        stride = (1, 1) if i == 0 else (2, 2)
        x = ResNet.residual_module(x, filters[i + 1], stride, chan_dim, reduce=True, bnEps=bnEps, bnMom=bnMom)
        
        for j in range(0, stages[i] - 1):
          x = ResNet.residual_module(x, filters[i + 1], (1, 1), chan_dim, bnEps=bnEps, bnMom=bnMom)
      
      x = BatchNormalization(axis=chan_dim, epsilon=bnEps, momentum=bnMom)(x)
      x = Activation("relu")(x)
      x = AveragePooling2D((8, 8))(x)
      
      if include_top:
        x = Flatten()(x)
        x = Dense(classes, kernel_regularizer=l2(reg))(x)
        x = Activation("softmax")(x)
        
      model = Model(inputs, x, name="resnet")
      
      if weights is not None:
        model.load_weights(weights)
        
      return model
```